# HTML files have disappeared from VS Code Project Folders

Tags: html, macos, visual-studio-code

Upon opening my VS Code project and selecting the single HTML file inside it, a prompt appeared stating that the HTML file doesn’t exist: “(Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file [file path])”. I opened the only other VS Code project I have containing an HTML file and the single HTML file within that project had disappeared as well.

I then opened Finder and, navigating to the two projects, found that there were no longer HTML files inside either project folders; only the CSS and JavaScript files I had created were there. Having not opened or touched the projects for about a week or so, I’m confused as to how these two HTML files in two different projects are both now “nonexistent.”

So far I’ve tried to show hidden files in Finder, look up the file names in Spotlight Search, check my Trash bin, and search for the file in my iCloud Drive. However, I still haven’t been able to find or recover the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the file extension from .html to .blade.php . Close your vs code and try to open your projects again.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't rename the files or change their extensions, as they don't even show up inside the VS Code project in Finder.

Comment: Maybe, do the rename of files before opening the project in VS Code. Try to first find the folder of your project in your pc and do the search of the files there. Give it a try, before we search for another solution.

Answer (score -1):

from the get started window open the folder or file there the drop down menu didn't work for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31006032)